# Amount of memory used by a process, how to get the same reading as Task Manager?

Tags: powershell, memory, process

Trying to get accurate memory usage of a process as shown in Task Manager.

Notepad.exe (Task Manager) : 2 856 KB

```
get-process notepad |
select name, description, @{l="Private Memory (MB)"; e={$_.privatememorysize / 1MB}}
```

This outputs: 4,8203125 (so around 4 820 KB)

Why is it much bigger?

To get the same amount i have to divide the private memory size by something close to 1675000 which makes no sense. For example this comes really close at  2,8561... But it cannot be used as a constant because it will give false readings for other amounts.

```
get-process notepad |
select name, description, @{l="Private Memory (MB)"; e={$_.privatememorysize / 1675000}}
```

Why is this and how do I get the same amount that is shown in Task Manager, where is it calculated from? Am I missing something here?

Comment: there are multiple parts to the reason ... [1] they are pro'ly not reading the same exact source. [2] they are _definitely_ not reading the source[s] at the same time. [3] they process the info in different ways - TaskManager does some averaging. ///// there are likely other factors, but those are the ones i recall from the last time this was asked. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks Lee, yeah I think I'll just use private memory size and ignore the difference. I just thought there was something special about the task manager and I was maybe getting it from the wrong place.

Comment: you are welcome! yes ... TaskManager is special, but it does not expose its code. you may want to look into the various counters you get in this list >>> `Get-Counter -ListSet *memory*` <<<. they have ways to get averages over time OR to get readings at intervals so you can see trends.